# Why there are no .rel.dyn/.got.plt section in dynamic ELF files?

Tags: c, linker, elf, dynamic-linking, got

I have code like this

```
// test_printf.c
#include <stdio.h>

int f(){
    printf("aaa %d\n", 1);
}
```

And I compile it with the following code

```
gcc -shared -fPIC -m32 -g -c -o test_printf.so test_printf.c
```

I think if run `readelf -S test_printf.so`, I will see `.rel.dyn` and `.rel.plt`. This is because both of these sections act like what `.rel.data` and `.rel.text` in static linked programs do.

For example, in my program, since `printf` is an external symbol, and is referred by my `test_printf.so`. So when I look into `test_printf.so`'s relocation table, there should be one entry names `printf`. I check that, and the entry exists.

Then I think, since `printf` is an external symbol, its location should be determined at runtime. However, we must allocate a `.got.plt` section for this `printf` function, and the section should be in both a dynamicly linked executive and a dynamic library(test_printf.so).

However, when I run `readelf -S`, there is no `.got.plt` section, and I am confused about this. Is this section not necessary in a dynamic library(test_printf.so)? I don't think it is possible. Suppose `test_printf.so` is finally linked with executive program `a`, then how can `a` know where is the `.got.plt` section for `printf`? Does this `.got.plt` finally generated in `a`?

Meanwhile, I have a question 2. Are `.rel.dyn` and `.rel.plt` always present, if there are `.got` and `.got.plt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.rel.dyn` and `.got.plt` can be present in a shared library `.elf` it depends on the structure of the functions in the library, this is in *https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html*

`.rela.dyn` is present if on extern function is included :

```
$ cat test.c
extern int foo;

int function(void) {
    return foo;
}
$ gcc -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so test.c
```

Also see  https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/ and
https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries

https://blog.ramdoot.in/how-can-i-link-a-static-library-to-a-dynamic-library-e1f25c8095ef  (linking static libraries into a dynamic library)